# Why am I having this error while trying to integrate a bootstrap template in an angular application?

Tags: angular, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am not really used to front-end development. So for my project, I am using a ready-made bootstrap template. And I am trying to integrate it in my project.
As you will notice, I am trying this intuitively rather than based on technical expertness since as I said I am new to front-end development.
So here's the template files and folders:
[image]
In the angular app, I have created four components:
- about
- contact
- portfolio
- work
In which I copied the correspondent html file.
The index file went into the app.component.html file.
Does this make sense?
Any way, in the app.component.html (previously index.html in the original template folder) I have changed the files path since the different assets (css/fonts/images/js/sass) are no longer in the same folder as the app.component.html (previously index.html in the original template folder). 
For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

becomes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Am I doing this the right way?
If so, why do I keep getting this error:

> GET http://localhost:4200/assets/css/bootstrap.css 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever angular serve it start the server with `PROJECT_DIR/src` directory -  i.e. localhost:4200 is pointing at the src folder and you are trying to fetch bootstrap.css from ../assets/css i.e. PROJECT_DIR, and assets folder is in the src folder. that's why it's throwing 404 not found.

you can include a stylesheet in index.html like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

neglecting ../ because of angular server dir is PROJECT_DIR/src folder.

otherwise, you can also include stylesheets in the angular.json file in styles array

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "vjs-ng-data-sharing-poc": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap.css" <-- your css file path
            ],
...
```

Comment: Alright, I will try that :). However, I would like to understand why isn't my method working if you don't mind :)

Comment: Thank you! I get it. I wonder why two people have downvoted my question